# Extended ext4 partition to include unallocated space, data seems unavailable now

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

This was all in an external hard disk.

This was the scenario:
I had 900GB of unallocated space and a 20GB ext4 partition. I used gparted to extend the etx4 partition across the entire disk.

After this, since there was some kind of warning in gparted (an exclamation icon beside the partition name) I clicked on repair. It started and said completed successfully.

On mounting the disk now the GUI shows no folders.

Also,
du -h gives the following:

```
4.0K    /media/user/61d564a3-1af1-460f-8508-f037b8088c1a/lost+found
8.0K    /media/user/61d564a3-1af1-460f-8508-f037b8088c1a
```

df -h

```
/dev/sdb2       917G   72M  871G   1% /media/user/61d564a3-1af1-460f-8508-f037b8088c1a
```

Have I lost the data? If yes, it has to be the rescue operation, right?

Edit: In Gparted it says used is 14.76 GB so the data might still just be there.

Comment: Is the data important? If so, do not use this disk for _anything_ until you've figured out how to recover it. Using the disk risks loosing the data, which currently does still exist on the disk.

Comment: `since there was some kind of warning in gparted (an exclamation icon beside the partition name) I clicked on repair` -- Did it say what the warning was exactly? In general it should have bothered you. Did you extend to the right? to the left? Knowing the warning and/or other details (the log from `gparted`?) may help us help you. Even now I expect you to be able to get (some) files back with `testdisk` (see [this](https://superuser.com/a/987169/432690)) or similar tool; or maybe the old filesystem at once? (possibly partially broken). But this is very generic advice.

Comment: I don't remember the warning. I extended it to the left, just dragged it all the way to the left end.